# Pinax and jquery: data("page") is undefined

Tags: jquery, pinax

I am working on Pinax and jQuery Mobile and a page keeps hanging. I saw following error in Firebug. I hope someone can suggest me a direction to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Chris

```
{u% extends "projects/base.html" %}
```

Also, there is a JavaScript error:

```
l.data("page") is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

By retrieving a page JQM searches for data-role="page". If it cannot find it you get "l.data("page") is undefined".
So I guess you need to add a data-role="page" in the html file you retrieve.